# How can I replace 'me()' term in FQL iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-fql

I am creating an iphone app using Facebook api. Here I'm using the following query to get the friends details;

```
NSString* fql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid,pic_square, name,online_presence FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY online_presence"];
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                fql1, @"query",
                                nil];
[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query" andParams:params andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate: self];
```

here, I need to replace the term 'me()' to make my project running. So, how can I do that, I have my (user's) ID, name in hand. So will it work if I replace the term me() with user id, user name. If yes, how can I do that? 
Please share your thoughts.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just replace the 'me()' with the uid of the user you're looking for the info of

Comment: I need to get the details of all users. So how can I do that?

Comment: i tried as you said but got an error "did fail: The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 104.)"

Comment: You're using an access token for the user you're replacing the 'me()' with, right? If the API call you're trying is the one in your post above, It's not possible to pull the friends list of any user other than the current session user

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you simply replace the  me() with the uid.

Comment: but i need to get the detail of my all friends, so does it work?

Comment: @John https://graph.facebook.com/<uid>/friends?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,<etc fields you want>&access_token=<access_token> ...